# I want to take name of column from user and match it with correlation matix columns and access values in that particular column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

## correlation between the columns, corr returns a correlation matrix

corr = df.corr()

## Enter the name of the column(variable) you want to select from the above correlation matrix

target_column = input(str())

## Now Match the target_column with column name of correlation matrix to access values of the column.

new_list = [i for i in corr if corr.columns.values == re.match(r'\w+', target_column)]
new_list

---

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

in ()
5
6 # Now Match the target_column with column name of
----> 7 new_list = [i for i in corr if corr.columns.values == re.match(r'\w+', target_column)]
8 new_list

in (.0)
5
6 # Now Match the target_column with column name of
----> 7 new_list = [i for i in corr if corr.columns.values == re.match(r'\w+', target_column)]
8 new_list

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

I am facing this error, what wrong I am doing in this code?

Comment: Won't `new_list = corr[target_column]` do it for you?

Comment: Yes, it solved my problem. Thanks